# flutter.buildMode=release shows unused property

Tags: gradle, flutter

After update my depencies such cloud_firestore, firebase_auth, fluttertoast and also gradle and android studio...
i have run flutter clean then flutter build apk - v
it was not working...
i switched stable version to master, nothing changed still the same issue.
that's a part of my log:

```
C:\sdk\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.9.13+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\fire
base\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java:627: warning: [deprecation] setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(boolean) in
Builder has been deprecated
[   +4 ms]             builder.setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(
[   +1 ms]                    ^
[ +299 ms] Note:
C:\sdk\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.9.13+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\fire
base\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[   +3 ms] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[   +1 ms] 1 warning
[   +3 ms] Note:
C:\sdk\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.3.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\
core\FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[   +2 ms] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[   +8 ms]
C:\sdk\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\fluttertoast-3.0.4\android\src\main\java\io\github\ponnamkarthik\toast
\fluttertoast\FluttertoastPlugin.java:84: warning: [deprecation] getDrawable(int) in Resources has been deprecated
[   +7 ms]                     shapeDrawable = ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.toast_bg);
[   +4 ms]                                                       ^
[   +4 ms] 1 warning
[+1703 ms] > Task :app:packageRelease FAILED
[ +240 ms]          *********************************************************
[  +70 ms] WARNING: This version of cloud_firestore will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't
compatible with AndroidX.
[   +5 ms]          See [https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility][here] for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
[   +2 ms]          This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be
unrelated.
[   +1 ms]          *********************************************************
[   +1 ms] 108 actionable tasks: 102 executed, 6 up-to-date
[ +744 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... (completed in 412,9s, longer than expected)
[   +9 ms] "flutter apk" took 597 734ms.
[  +11 ms] "flutter apk" took 597 734ms.
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: I think that is just warning. You can just simply ignore it.

Comment: The real error should be something else

Comment: But i'm not able to build the release apk only the debug apk

Comment: Release build is more strict than debug build. So, it is normal that might get a compile error on release build but not on debug build. To know what's your real compile error on release build, could you please paste the compile error log here?

Answer (score 0):

You must update to AndroidX and also update the Firebase libraries.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

Look at this part of the log:

[ +240 ms]          *********************************************************
[  +70 ms] WARNING: This version of cloud_firestore will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't
compatible with AndroidX.
[   +5 ms]          See [https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility][here] for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
[   +2 ms]          This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be
unrelated.
[   +1 ms]          *********************************************************